# SECRET_KEY_BASE missing error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, puma, secret-key

SECRET_KEY_BASE missing error on production while I have placed secret token export command in `.profile` and `.bashrc`

my export command is like this:

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=21021dd33712b563e*******************
```

in pumma access logs it shows me this error

```
2015-12-23 06:32:28 -0500: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing    `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set     these values in `config/secrets.yml`>
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-  4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:534:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:79:in `call'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
 /home/deploy/apps/pulsemedia/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
```

Here is my secrets.yml file

```
 production:

    secret_key_base: <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

I try `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` in rails console production it shows me key there but I don't know whats happening.

Note: I am using rails 4.2.1

Comment: Are you certain your puma process is running under the same account as your environment variable? Also ... you might find that your puma process does not trigger the execution of your `.profile` or `.bashrc` files.

Comment: yup I manually ran these commands as well but nothing happend.

Comment: what web server do you use on production (unicorn/passenger etc)? it can lose custom environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I killed pumma process and restart using this command

`bundle exec puma -C /home/deploy/path_to/shared/puma.rb`

Woked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Type on your shell

```
   rake secret
```

Then replace

```
    <%= ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE'] %>
```

with the result.